# How do I return a value and a JSX element using the ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm trying to do two things at once when someone clicks on a button to send an email. The code below changes the text of the button to "Sending..." and adds the JSX element `<CircularProgress/>`

```
<Button   
    className={submitButton}
    type="submit"
    disabled={emailStatus === "loading"}
    >        
{emailStatus === "loading" ? ("Sending..." ): "Send Email"}
{emailStatus === "loading" && (<CircularProgress size={24}/>)}
 </Button>
```

As you can see I'm checking the email status twice using the ternary operator.

How can I put it all into one, maybe like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<Button   
    className={submitButton}
    type="submit"
    disabled={emailStatus === "loading"}
    >        
{emailStatus === "loading" ? ("Sending..." , <CircularProgress size={24}/> ): "Send Email"}
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them inside one parent element and then render that.

```js
<>
 Sending ...
 <CircularProgress size={24}/>
</>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for :)